# Artifactory - Cannot create a repository linked to a private nuget feed (grial)

Tags: nuget, artifactory, nuget-package

We are using a nuget repository named Grial (https://docs.grialkit.com/)

In our artifactory instance, we are not able to define a remote repository linked to Grial

For instance, we can go to : *host:port/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget/Packages(Id='UXDivers.Grial',Version='3.2.87')* without any problem

But the download part (*host:port/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget/Download/UXDivers.Grial/3.2.87*) raises an 404 not implemented error :

```
The feed 'NuGet [https://host:port/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget/]' lists package 'UxDivers.Grial.3.2.87' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
```

I think the NuGet Download Context Path is wrong in our config, but i have no idea what it should be.

Is there anyone in the community who has already experienced an issue like this with a private nuget repository ?

**Edit (comment from Muhammed Kashif):**

URL: `http://nuget.uxdivers.com/grial`

NuGet Download Context Path: `api/nuget/v3`

NuGet Feed Context Path:

NuGet v3 Feed URL:

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to create a nuget remote repository to connect to Grail? If so, could you please elaborate the URL used? If not, what is the remote repository configuration that is failing? It seems the NuGet Download Context Path is wrong and it also depends on whether you are fetching v2 or v3 packages?

Comment: Yes exactly, i'am trying to create a nuget remote repository, I've added the relevant infos in my original post

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved my issue.

For anyone who is facing the same issue, I let my config below:

URL: `http://nuget.uxdivers.com`

NuGet Download Context Path: `api/nuget/v2`

NuGet Feed Context Path: `grial`

NuGet v3 Feed URL: